# Can 'Talk aloud' be used?

Tags: vocabulary

> Don’t talk **aloud** in the library.

Can I use ‘*aloud*’ or not, in the sentence above? From my Koran English dictionary, except ‘*(idiomatic)* *cry [shout] aloud*,’ they don’t use the word to denote ‘*[in a loud voice](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/aloud)*,'  or it is archaic. And I can tell that it could be expanded into ‘*[laugh/groan aloud](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/aloud)*’ from Longman. Could it be further expanded into ‘*talk aloud*’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aloud* does not mean the same thing as *loud*.  Rather, *aloud* is the opposite of *silently*.

It's possible to read silently, and therefore, it is also possible to *read aloud*.  Also, it's possible to think silently, and therefore, you can also say *think aloud* in contrast.

On the other hand, it's questionable whether you can talk silently, so *talking aloud* would also be dubious usage.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence with an adverb *loudly* sounds natural, at least to my ears. That's because I have heard teachers and parents telling that to their children.

> Don't speak/talk loudly in the library

On the other hand, I have heard natives advising their kids to [*read aloud* as in here.](http://www.education.com/reference/article/reasons-teach-children-read-aloud/)

In addition, as you are concerned, an *aloud* is a word which means *talking in high pitch/volume,* not necessarily crying. [WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ALOUD) defines it.